# Can't successfully perform a Get with WebAPI in Local IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I written a WebAPI that fetches records. I got it to work in debug mode with the Visual Studio server and i was able to save the json file that was 50KB. I deployed the WebAPI service to my local IIS and went to Browse to successfully bring up the page. When I call the controller in the URL, it could not download the json file and fails. Basically, it works in debug but not with local IIS. Then we change the connection string from

server=My_Server;database=test_db;integrated security=sspi

to

server=My_Server;database=test_db;integrated security=false;user id=Me; password=password123"

For some reason, the integrated security=sspi did not work with local IIS but when I go to production we need to specify integrated security=sspi in the connection string.

I was told that I can configure IIS to make integrated security=sspi work. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- IIS vs VS 
  You have to properly setup your web application in IIS (app pool, bindings, permissions, etc). VS does all of this "automagically" for you in dev, but it's (a little bit) more involved when actually going IIS.
  *I haven't done this in a while* but try *publishing* to your local IIS and see if it does all (or at least some/most?) of the grunt work....
- [SQL with Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)